# How or Why Hive is allowing alter table? Is it NOT violating HDFS's Write Once Read Many

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Hive runs on HDFS. And its default destination is '/user/hive/warehouse' within HDFS.
With Hive we can create table and 'ALTER'.  Altering table includes deleting/modifying existing columns in the table (residing somewhere in HDFS!!!). Whatever written to HDFS cannot be modified.  But hive's alter is doing the same. How is that possible? Any idea!

Answer (score 1):

You only change the metadata of the table - not the data itself.

Also, notice that there is no `drop column` directive in hive.

Comment: There is no drop column but there is possibility to drop/create external table. it's possible to remove last column(s) from the table built over text files.

Comment: True, but that would require processing all the files and storing the new altered table somewhere... The question was how hive doesn't violate HDFS's write once policy

Comment: No, I mean that this will also work without file processing. table will not read deleted columns if those columns are last (at the end of the list).

Comment: I get what you mean. You are right. By only changing the metadata hive can ignore last columns.

Comment: This means the Hive's 'metadata' is NOT part of HDFS. And, any change on table is first reflected in 'metadata'.  Considering this as 'true': I have created a table with three columns and dumped huge data. Later dropped the last column. Metadata knows about this. But actual data on 'HDFS' is NOT deleted. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. notice that there is no drop column - you change the way hive parses the data. Some hive directives do change the data on HDFS such as: DROP (internal) TABLE, DROP PARTITION or LOAD.